# How to go about creating a word count program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, word-count

The program should accept file names as input and then print three numbers showing:

1. the count of lines
2. count of words words
3. count of characters in the file.

Im really not sure where to start on this question. Please help.

Comment: I'd start by opening a file and counting words. If you're going to post every single assignment you've got there, then at least *try* to write something, nobody will write your homework for you.

Comment: Honestly, all your requirements individually are fairly trivial in Python. Google a little, work on each one and then put it together.

Comment: not home work just trying to self teach a little but will do.

Comment: Don't expect that we do your homework...we must not teach you  very basic tutorial stuff...this is kind of lazy...

Comment: @kris: +1 for bowing to peer pressure. ;-)

Comment: What language? Word separation are not a trivial issue in languages that doesn't use spaces.

Comment: I found this interesting: http://tinyurl.com/maybeHelpsU

Answer (score 4):

here's a pseudo-code to help you get started.

```
open file handle
set counter_line=0
set counter_word=0
set counter_char=0
while iterate file
   increment counter_line
   split line into array
   counter_word += length of split array
   counter_char += length of line
end while
close file handle
```